# I don't get why the answer is 5-diamond? It could also be Queen-heart and 4-heart.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinations, game-theory, puzzle, combinatorial-game-theory

The aim is for A and B to guess the right card from the below deck of cards.

[image]

A is told the **number** only of the card.

B is told the **shape** only of the card.

Based on the following conversation between A and B, A and B manage to guess correctly the right card.

1. A: *I don't know the card*.
2. B: *Before you mentioned, I already know you don't know, but I still don't know*.
3. A: *Now, I know the card.*
4. B: *I also know the card now.*

**Ok so my question is: Why is the answer 5 diamond? It could also be Queen-heart and 4-heart.**

From 1, the message from A provides me the information that the right card has at least 1 other card with the same number though different symbol. As such, I can already rule out those cards without at least 1 other card with the same number.

From 2, the message from B provides me and A some information about the symbol of the right card. I can already rule out ALL spade and club because 8 spade and 6 club do not have at least one other card of the same number but different symbol.

[image: Narrowing down the few possible right cards]

From 3, the message from A provides me and B information that Ace heart and Ace diamond can be ruled out because after A received B's message from Line 2, A can decisively know the answer.

[image]

Now **here lies the confusion for me -- hope some kind soul can enlighten me --** how could B reply "I also know the card" and choose 5 diamond because, at least to me, there is not enough information for B to conclude logically that it is 5 diamond.

It could also be Queen-heart and 4-heart.

Comment: It's because B saw that the card was a diamond, and the only diamond left is the 5 of diamonds.

Comment: @JosephCamacho so if the right card is either Queen-heart or 4-heart the reply for B will be I still don't know?

Answer (score 1):

Yep thanks @JosephCamacho for pointing out my confusion.

From 4, the message from B provides me the information about the right card is 5 diamond because B can decisively make a choice. Supposed if the right card is queen-heart and 4-heart, B cannot make the statement that "I also know the card now" because he will be stuck between queen-heart and 4-heart.

Ahhh can't believe I got stuck at this simple logic -.-"

Comment: In short, it is because you forgot you are not B.  :D